# How to validate edit text with to allow user enter integer and float for price field in android

Tags: android

How to validate edit text with to allow user  enter integer and float value for price in android

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In XML add attribute to editText : `android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal"` for signed floating point number.

Answer (score 0):

Use inputtype of EditText:

```
android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
```